# Download a file in a specific directory using FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

I made a little form and I want it to save it as PDF. I managed to set up everything using FPDP but I'd like to download the file on a specific directory (let's say a folder) as soon as I hit the save button.

This is my code for FPDF

```
    <?php
session_start();
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
$sicep = $_SESSION['sicep'];
$notesicep = $_SESSION['notesicep'];

require ('fpdf/fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();

$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',11);

$pdf->Cell(100, 8, 'Operatore Centrale Operativa: '.$user, 1 ,1);
$pdf->Cell(100, 8, 'Effettuato in data: ' .date("d/m/Y"). ' In ora: '.date("h:ia") , 1 ,1);
$pdf->Cell(180, 10, 'Verifica funzionale sistema SICEP MVS NET:',1,1);
$pdf->Cell(180, 10, $sicep,1,1);
$pdf->Cell(180, 10, 'Note: '.$notesicep,1,1);

$pdf->Output("D", date("d/m/Y")."-".date("h:ia").".pdf");
?>
```

I managed to save the file name with current date and time but I'd also like to automatic download the file on a certian directory, let's say on the desktop:

> C:\Users\user\Desktop

but I can't find a way to do it. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to decide on php level where to store the file on user's machine (when you click download button, you'll get dialog window to choose location or it will use default browser settings).

If you would like to store it in specific directory (on the server) you can add path to the `output()` method, for example like this:

```
$pdf->Output("D", '/some/path/' . date("d/m/Y")."-".date("h:ia").".pdf");
```